# $P[X_n\:\mathrm{converges}] = 0$ for iid non-constant RVs

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I came across this problem while studying for an exam.

If the sequence $\{X_n\}$ is **iid** Random variables and not constant with probability $1$, then 
$P[X_n\:\mathrm{converges}] = 0$.

Apparently, by Kolmogorov Zero-One Law, this probability is either 0 or 1, but how to prove that it is equal to 0?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1460355/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find some $x\lt y$ such that $P(X_1\leqslant x)$ and $P(X_1\geqslant y)$ are both positive. Then, almost surely, $X_n\leqslant x$ for infinitely many $n$ and $X_n\geqslant y$ for infinitely many $n$, thus, almost surely,
$$
\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\leqslant x,\qquad\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\geqslant y.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Quick proof of the contrapositive:

Suppose that $X_n$ converges with positive probability.  Then by the Kolmogorov 0-1 law, it converges almost surely, to some random variable we will call $X$.  In particular, $X_n \to X$ in distribution, and the $X_n$ all have the same distribution, so $X$ has that distribution as well.  On the other hand, $X$ is a tail random variable, so by Kolmogorov again, it is constant.  Hence all the $X_n$ are constant too.